# How can i make my CSS class to fit my image size?

Tags: html, css, razor

Hi I have `image` of this size :

```
   <div class="listRowA"  onmouseover="this.className='listRowAHover'"  onmouseout="this.className='listRowA'"> 


             <div class="listPageCol"  onclick="location.href='../Home/ControlPanel'">
                  <span class="listCol1">

                 <br />
                  @Model[i].ID
                   </span>
                 <span class="Col2"><img src="../Content/Images/20_thumb.jpg" width="281" height="200" border="0" alt="image"  /></span>


         </div>
         </div>
```

And I have this CSS style which I am applying over this `image`:

```
.listRowA {
    border: 1px solid #fff; 
}

.listRowAHover { 
    background-color: #F4E4E4; 
    border: 1px solid #fff; 
}
```

My hover style :

```
   .listPageCol {
padding:5px; 
margin-right:75px; 
cursor:pointer;

   }
```

Here problem I am facing is when I hover my image I can see `pointer` and `background-color` outside my image also.So how can I fix this to fit to my `image`?

Comment: use `display: block` to the `img` tag. btw, what is `.listRowA` and `.listRowAHover`?

Comment: maybe it should be .listRowA:hover ? Also, the image should have class="listRowA"

Comment: you need to remove hover class to fix this issue

Comment: Why are you wrapping it in a span tag ?

Comment: @Mr_Green Its not working. I used like this :  <span class="Col2"><img src="../Content/Images/20_thumb.jpg"  style="display:block" width ="281" height="200" border="0" alt ="image"  /></span>

Comment: ok but how you are hovering img element? Do you know what ".listRowA" and ".listRowAHover" are referring to?

Comment: the question seems to be unclear. hmmm... maybe specify the width and height on the hover too. By the way, what problems are you facing with the cursor? To set the cursor to default, you can use cursor:default; on your css

Comment: @SumitBijvani If i remove hover class then i loose background color when user hovers on image. I want this feature.

Comment: @Mr_Green I updated my post.Please have a look into that for how i am hovering..

Comment: show us the complete markup, with `.listRowA` and `.listPageCol`

Comment: @koala_dev I updated my post.Have a look into that..

Comment: I agree @koala_dev. This question lacks some more information.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<span class="Col2">
<img src="../Content/Images/20_thumb.jpg" width="281" height="auto" border="0"  alt="image"  />
```

or

The solution is to put the image as background-image and then set the background-size to contain

**HTML**

```
<div class='bounding-box'>
```

**CSS**

```
.bounding-box {


 background-image: url(...);


background-repeat: no-repeat;


 background-size: contain;
}
```